# Drawing inner shadow for Bezier curves in OpenGL / GLSL

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, glsl, glsles

I'm trying to draw an inner glow/shadow for an object consisting of four cubic Bezier curves. To draw a single Bezier curve I'm splitting it into segments and then calculating distances from current pixel to each line segment and finally I'm blending it with `min`:

`// No GL_MAX blending mode in OpenGL ES 2.0
d_min = min(d_min, d)`

where `d` is a distance for every segment. Zoomed in example of blending two line segments:

[image]

It works reasonably well when you have ~25 segments representing a short Bezier curve

[image]

except for "gutters" in the places where Bezier curves and their respective gradients combine.

**Q:** How can I avoid these artifacts? Is there a better method for drawing inner glow/shadow?

[image]

Comment: this [Draw Quadratic Curve on GPU](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31423105/2521214) might help a bit

Answer (score 1):

What about doing a blur on your curves and then masking the result to the inside area?

Comment: Yep, this is how Photoshop does it. I'm not sure why the OP gets the artifacts he gets though.

Answer (score 0):

see:

- [GLSL rendering 2D cubic BEZIER curves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60113617/2521214)

It basically convert inputted 4-vertex geometry chunks into BEZIER cubics with defined curve width `d`.

In fragment you got information about distance to curve `ll` so you can use it directly to shade your stuff. For your case using white background and black color and these points:

```
double pnt[]=                   // cubic curve control points
    {
    +0.9,-0.8,0.0,
    +0.5,+0.8,0.0,
    -0.5,+0.8,0.0,
    -0.9,-0.8,0.0,
    };
```

I got this output (`d=0.05`):

[image: output]

I just change the final coloring line in vertex shader to:

```
l=ll/d; // distance from center of curve 0..1
col=vec4(l,l,l,1.0);
```

You can un-linearize the `l` by `sqrt` or `pow` to enhance the shading effect...