# GLSL Parametric Curve Plotter

Tags: glsl, shader, curve, parametric-equations

I am trying to implement a parametric curve plotter on a fragment shader in GLSL.

I managed to make a rudimentary one by iterating the parameter and drawing a circle for each computed position.

You can find the (working and commented) code [here](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4djczm).

Here are my questions:

- I would like to plot it with a line. From what I have understood, I see two different ways I could do it :

  1. by computing the distance between each pixel and the computed position inside the loop, accumulate the computed value in a float variable, and then draw the curve using a step function.

     I tried doing this and it seems like I only compute the distance for the one t position:

     ```
     #define PI 3.14

     void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
     {
         vec2 uv = -1. + 2.*fragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;
         uv.x *= iResolution.x/iResolution.y;
         vec3 color = vec3(0.);
         vec2 pos;
         float dist;

         for(float t=-2.; t<2.02; t+=.02){

             pos.x = sin(4.*t+(iGlobalTime));
             pos.y = cos(6.*t);

             dist += 1.-sqrt(pow((uv.x-pos.x),2.)+pow((uv.y-pos.y),2.));

             color += vec3(dist);


         }//for

         fragColor = mix(vec4(0.0), vec4(1.0), dist);

     }
     ```
  2. By drawing line segment between each consecutive positions of the parameter

     I found [this implementation](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XdSGzh) that seems to do what I am trying to achieve, but i don't quite understand why they are using the previous position of the parameter.
- Is there a way to do such a function without a for loop managing the parameter?

Last precision : I'm only suing a fragment shader because my goal is to upload it on a VJing software that manages fragment shaders

Comment: take a look at [Draw Quadratic Curve on GPU](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31423105/2521214)

Comment: Either evaluate the curve on the CPU, or in a compute shader, then use your vert and frag shaders to draw it. Your current approach performs a ton of redundant work which defeats the purpose of using the GPU.